# How to fill missing values relative to a value from another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, missing-data

I'd like to fill missing values with conditions relative to the country:
For example, I'd want to replace China's missing values with the mean of Age and for USA it's the median of Age. For now, I don't want to touch of EU's missing values.
How could I do realise it ?
Below the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['USA', ], ['EU', 15], ['China', 35],
       ['USA', 45], ['EU', 30], ['China', ],
       ['USA', 28], ['EU', 26], ['China', 78],
       ['USA', 65], ['EU', 53], ['China', 66],
       ['USA', 32], ['EU', ], ['China', 14]]  

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Country', 'Age'])
df.head(10)

  Country   Age
0     USA   NaN
1      EU  15.0
2   China  35.0
3     USA  45.0
4      EU  30.0
5   China   NaN
6     USA  28.0
7      EU  26.0
8   China  78.0
9     USA  65.0
10    EU    NaN
```

Thank you

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it but it is one way to do it

```
age_series = df['Age'].copy()
df.loc[(df['Country'] == 'China') & (df['Age'].isnull()), 'Age'] = age_series.mean()
df.loc[(df['Country'] == 'USA') & (df['Age'].isnull()), 'Age'] = age_series.median()
```

Note that I copied the `age` column before hand so that you get the `median` of the original age series not after calculating the mean for the US. This is the final results

```
    Country     Age
0   USA     33.500000
1   EU      15.000000
2   China   35.000000
3   USA     45.000000
4   EU      30.000000
5   China   40.583333
6   USA     28.000000
7   EU      26.000000
8   China   78.000000
9   USA     65.000000
10  EU      53.000000
11  China   66.000000
12  USA     32.000000
13  EU      NaN
14  China   14.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try this

```
df['Age']=(np.where((df['Country'] == 'China') & (df['Age'].isnull()),df['Age'].mean()
          ,np.where((df['Country'] == 'USA') & (df['Age'].isnull()),df['Age'].median(),df['Age']))).round()
```

**Output**

```
   Country  Age
0   USA     34.0
1   EU      15.0
2   China   35.0
3   USA     45.0
4   EU      30.0
5   China   41.0
6   USA     28.0
7   EU      26.0
8   China   78.0
9   USA     65.0
10  EU      53.0
11  China   66.0
12  USA     32.0
13  EU      NaN
14  China   14.0
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, we can create a function to handle this as it's not easily automated (although I may be wrong)

the idea is to pass in the country name & fill type (i.e mean median) you can extend the function to add in your agg types.

it returns a data frame that modifies yours, so you can use this to assign it back to your col

```
def missing_values(dataframe,country,fill_type):

    """
    takes 3 arguments, dataframe, country & fill_type:
    fill_type is the method used to fill `NA` values, mean, median, etc.
    """

    fill_dict = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Country'] == country]\
            .groupby("Country")["Age"].agg(
                    ["mean", "median"]).to_dict(orient='index')



    dataframe.loc[dataframe['Country'] == country, 'Age'] \
                 = dataframe['Age'].fillna(fill_dict[country][fill_type])
    return dataframe
```

---

```
print(missing_values(df,'China','mean')
    Country    Age
0      USA    NaN
1       EU  15.00
2    China  35.00
3      USA  45.00
4       EU  30.00
5    China  48.25
6      USA  28.00
7       EU  26.00
8    China  78.00
9      USA  65.00
10      EU  53.00
11   China  66.00
12     USA  32.00
13      EU    NaN
14   China  14.00
```

---

```
print(missing_values(df,'USA','median'))
   Country    Age
0      USA  38.50
1       EU  15.00
2    China  35.00
3      USA  45.00
4       EU  30.00
5    China  48.25
6      USA  28.00
7       EU  26.00
8    China  78.00
9      USA  65.00
10      EU  53.00
11   China  66.00
12     USA  32.00
13      EU    NaN
14   China  14.00
```